# JavaScript Error in Webkit

Tags: javascript, webkit

I've written a script that decreases the width of a div if a variable is equal to true, then sets it to false. If the variable is equal to false, it increases the width of the div. The code for this is:

```
var open = false;
function chat() {
    if (!open) {
        document.getElementById("frameholder").innerHTML="div is wide";
        document.getElementById("window").style.width="1300px";
        document.getElementById("window").style.marginLeft="-650px";
        open = true;
    }
}
function unchat() {
    if (open) {
        setTimeout("document.getElementById('frameholder').innerHTML='div is skinny'",500);
        document.getElementById("window").style.width="900px";
        document.getElementById("window").style.marginLeft="-450px";
        open = false;
    }
}
```

The HTML is something like this...

```
<a href="#" onclick="chat()">Open chat</a><br />
<a href="#" onclick="unchat()">Close chat</a>
<div id="window">
  <div id="video">
  </div>
  <div id="frameholder">
  </div>
</div>
```

For some reason, this only works once in Chrome (webkit). I can expand the div, then shrink the div, but I can't re-expand it. It works fine in Firefox and IE. Any idea why?

EDIT: Updated my code to the current state and added HTML example. Unfortunately I'm still having the same problem...

EDIT 2: I give up on this. This page is mostly for my use anyway, and I almost exclusively use Firefox, so I suppose it's not really that big of an issue.

Comment: `open == true`?  Silly. How about `(open == true) == true`? Need to understand what a boolean is.

Comment: a copy of the error might be helpful.

Comment: To elaborate on @awm's comment, you should change `if (open == true)` to `if (open)`, and change `if (open == false)` to `if (!open)`.

Comment: @awm thats probably from a copy-paste and your comment really doesn't help.

Comment: @Rev awm's comment was trying to prove a point. It was not an actual suggestion.

Comment: @Rev no, no, no.  Please read Matt's comment, not mine.

Comment: Also, there's no need for the empty `else` statements. Remove them.

Comment: Does it make a difference that I'm using `<a href="#" onclick="chat()">Open Chat</a>` and `<a href="#" onclick="unchat()">Remove Chat</a>` for how I'm running the code? It actually uses images for the links, so if I could avoid buttons that'd be helpful...

Comment: @Rev: Buttons would be semantically more correct as your links don't link anywhere. You can always style the buttons with CSS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this ought to do it:

```
var open = false,
    $button = document.getElementById('clickme'),
    $frameholder = document.getElementById('frameholder'),
    $window = document.getElementById('window'),
    timer;

function toggleChat()
{
    clearTimeout(timer);
    if (open)
    {
        timer = setTimeout(function ()
        {
            $frameholder.innerHTML="div is skinny";
        }, 500);
        $window.style.width="900px";
        $window.style.marginLeft="-450px";
    }
    else
    {
        timer = setTimeout(function ()
        {
            $frameholder.innerHTML="div is wide";
        }, 500);
        $window.style.width="1300px";
        $window.style.marginLeft="-650px";
    }
    open = !open;
}

toggleChat();

$button.addEventListener('click', toggleChat, false);
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/nuzyJ/

---

Re OP comment:

> That looks like a lot of extra code

You can do this *much* more concisely and cleanly with jQuery+CSS classes, and it will work across a larger range of browsers as well. I've omitted the frameholder text change for brevity, but here's the idea:

```
var $frameholder = $('#frameholder'),
    $window = $('#window');

$('#clickme').click(function ()
{
    $window.toggleClass('wide');
}).click();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/pgTJn/

Comment: That looks like a lot of extra code...plus that demo doesn't work.

Comment: @Rev see my edit. I recommend using a library (jQuery is the frequently-recommended one these days) which eliminates 99.9% of the cross-browser issues you'll see in JavaScript.

Comment: @Rev I edited again to fix the Firefox problem - `addEventListener` was missing an argument. That's the kind of cross-browser issues that jQuery (and other JS libraries like MooTools, Dojo, YUI, RightJS, Prototype...) smooths out for you.